# Updating data without ajax or logging of request in network tab - Websocekts

Tags: javascript, html, angular, websocket, xmlhttprequest

I found a website which is updating its trade data which seems to be like using AJAX but there is not log of any kind of request at the network panel of chrome.

See image below -

[image: Trade table and coin prices are getting updated, but no log]

Again now, from same session -

[image: Trade table and coin prices are getting updated]

My assumption is these prices are getting updated from a JSON as tracker API is given at the footer - https://koinex.in/api/ticker
But no console.log or network log is there for these update, and these rates are updating really very fast, try visiting and have a look.

**Does anyone knows what are they using by which they are able to hide the request.**

Note - Website is in angular as it have ng-directives
Ref - - https://koinex.in/exchange/ripple

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are using WebSocket to refresh data. Check WS or WebSocket tabs on your [Developer Console](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/reference).

It is one of the best practices when you are working on rapidly changing data and want to show it to your users.

> **WebSocket** is an advanced technology that makes it possible to open an
>   interactive communication session between the user's browser and a
>   server. With this API, you can send messages to a server and receive
>   event-driven responses without having to poll the server for a reply. [(read more)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API)

Answer (score 1):

It's done via websockets. You can verify this by reloading the page while the Network tab is open and you will notice an entry of type websocket down the list of status 101.
[image: list of network]
 If you click this entry, and then in the main pane of network click on 'Frames', you will see the data being exchanged.
[image]